# Set npm private registry with dotnet restore

Tags: jenkins, npm, asp.net-core, .net-core, npm-install

We have a private registry for npm. I'm getting an npm error running dotnet publish. Is there a way to specify the npm private registry. (This is on a build server, jenkins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by setting an environment variable (NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set registry <URL>
```

should also works, or create variable in repository in [.npmrc file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc)